# Batch to Copy file to another folder and Add LastModifiedDate to the destination file

Tags: batch-file, last-modified

thanks in advance.

I need to create a batch that uses XCOPY to copy one file to another folder and need to add Last Modified Date and Time to the new file.

Source file is "\Files\Data\Production\EOM Reporting\EOM Working Files\Expanded Aging EOM.xlsb"

Destination should be "\Files\Data\Production\EOM Reporting\EOM Working Files\archive\Expanded Aging EOM ****LastModifiedDateTime****.xlsb"

I have tried a couple of methods but no luck!

thanks!

Comment: The format for LastModifiedDateTime is ... and the value is retrieved from ....

Comment: Show what methods you tried.